# Profile embedded Python Function in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have embedded a python function into C++ and want to profile it (like in the [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#importing-modules)):

```
py::module calc = py::module::import("calc");
py::object result = calc.attr("add")(1, 2);
int n = result.cast<int>();
```

calc.py:

```
"""calc.py located in the working directory"""

def add(i, j):
    return i + j
```

Is there a way to profile it without timing explicitly in your code but instead with a package like [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler). Like this:

```
"""calc.py located in the working directory"""
@profile
def add(i, j):
    return i + j
```

When I add the decorator I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
  what():  NameError: name 'profile' is not defined
```

The package is installed via pip in global environment.

Comment: When you open a python shell and execute the same commands as in the cpp file, does it work?

Comment: The same error from python shell. So how should I define it?

Comment: If the problem occurs from the python shell too, the problem isn't with your pybind11 interface. Are you importing the `profile` command at the top of the file?

Comment: @RomeoValentin yes thank you this was the problem sorry